# Protobuf groups and messages

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a question regarding `message` and `group` intercompatibility. Can data encoded with first `proto` be decoded with second `proto` structures? Or they have different wire formats and are not intercompatible?

First `proto`:

```
message SearchResponse {
  repeated group Result = 1 {
    required string url = 2;
    optional string title = 3;
    repeated string snippets = 4;
  }
}
```

Second `proto`:

```
message SearchResponse {
  message Result {
    required string url = 2;
    optional string title = 3;
    repeated string snippets = 4;
  }

  repeated Result result = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` uses a different encoding style, and most serializers will outright refuse to work compatibly between them. Since you specifically added the [protobuf-net](/questions/tagged/protobuf-net) tag, I will note that protobuf-net is a bit more forgiving here, and *should* work interchangeably, but I probably wouldn't get into the habit of doing that very often. As a side note, `group` is largely deprecated by Google and the *details* don't even appear in the encoding specification any more (it just mentions that they exist and are deprecated).